# How to generate ObjectId() when manually inserting in Robo 3T?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, robo3t

I'm trying to generate ObjectId() when inserting manually in Robo 3T.

Code below seems doesn't work. I wanted every object inside TestArray have a unique id.

How do I generate ObjectId manually?

```
{
    "Name" : "Test",
    "TestArray" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId(),
            "Name" : "Test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
 new ObjectId()
```

This will generate the objectId on client side

Comment: It doesn't work.
I tried:
{
    "Name" : "Test",
    "Statuses" : [ 
        {
            "_id": new ObjectId(),
            "Name" : "Test"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Note that I am inserting manually in Robo3T. I right click the collection then insert document.

Comment: From the robo console it must work ....

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

```
x=ObjectId();
```

and it works fine for me

[image]

Comment: how do I put it inside TestArray under _id?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to generate the _id, just don't that field in your insert query and mongo will automatically generate it for you.

Comment: Based on my example it will only generate at the top of the document. But not inside an array.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
var TestArray = []    
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   TestArray.push({ "_id": ObjectId(), "Name": "Test" }) 

{
    "Name" : "Test",
    "TestArray" : TestArray
}
```

Comment: Is that a C# code? Note that I am manually inserting data in the collection using Robo3T

Comment: No, it is Javascript. The mongo shell is also a Javascript environment, the new `mongosh` is even a Node.js environment. No idea, whether Robo3T already uses the new `mongosh`

Comment: In my Robo3T it is working.

Answer (score 0):

While this is pretty tedious, if you want to use the typical Meteor structure of a 17 character alphanumeric string, you can use a random text generator online to generate a string, then do a `.find()` in the collection to see if it exists, and then pass it in your `.insert()` as the `_id` value in your insert object. I had the same problem and this was the way I got around it.